# What's the relationship between Claire and Stephen in Southcliffe?

Tags: southcliffe

Has anyone worked out the relationship between Claire Salter and Stephen Morton yet? They both care for Stephen's mum. Claire appears to have an office job and so is unlikely to be a professional carer. She could be Stephen's sister, although something about the way they talk to each other makes me think that isn't the case. Have I missed something or do we just not know yet?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Channel 4](http://www.channel4.com/info/press/programme-information/southcliffe) (who commissioned the four-part drama);

> ***Claire Salter (Shirley Henderson) is a committed social worker, carer
>   to Queenie*** [Stephen Morton's Mother]*, consumed by her own private
>   anxieties. On this morning, a spree-killer suddenly and randomly
>   commits a spate of shootings, leaving the innocent residents of
>   Southcliffe faced with emotions they are unequipped to understand or
>   deal with.*

As to why she's office-based, it's important to distinguish between a [Social Carer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_care_in_England) and a [Social Worker](http://www.prospects.ac.uk/social_worker_job_description.htm).